# MVC - Get List of values from Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm new in MVC asp.net and I want print a list of data stored in my mdf database (there is already some data) using entity Framework. I'm trying follow the microsoft's mvc tutorial and doing some changes to learn manipulating this.
My controller code is:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var data= storeDB.GenreTable.ToList();
    return View(data);
}
```

At html code I have:

```
@model IEnumerable<projectTest.Models.Genre>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }

<ul>
    @foreach (var genre in Model)
    {
        <li>@Html.ActionLink(genre.description, "Browse", new {genre = genre.description})</li>
    }
</ul>
```

when I go to test I receive

> 'The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[projectTest.genre]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[projectTest.Models.Genre]'

What could be the solution of this? I already tried to change some configurations in my web.config. Many thanks!

Comment: It looks like you have two "genre" classes.  One is in the `Models` namespace called `Genre` and one is outside of that namespace called `genre`.  The view is expecting one of them, but you're supplying the other one.  You probably didn't mean to have two of them in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is very explicit in what the problem is in this instance.  You have decorated your view with the following:

```
@model IEnumerable<projectTest.Models.Genre>
```

But, you are passing this as your model

```
storeDB.GenreTable.ToList();
```

which is a list of `projectTest.Genre`.  In order to make this work, you either need to update your view to accept an IEnumerable of the type you are passing:

```
@model IEnumerable<projectTest.Genre>
```

Or, you need to pass the correct view model back to your view, using something like the following (since I don't know what the `projectTest.Models.Genre` class looks like):

```
var data= storeDB.GenreTable.Select(x=>new projectTest.Models.Genre{
    name = x.Name, 
    description = x.Description
}).ToList();
```

Comment: ahh.. ok! I see! Many Thanks Tommy!
Just one more question:
If I use the Entity Frameworks I don't need create models am I right?

Comment: That is correct blackout12. Your Entity Framework is your model. If you need to add calculated properties to your model, you can always create partial classes to extend your Entity Framework:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx

Note: the generated AND your own created partial class have to have the exact same namespace for this to work.